# Check if Fragment exists

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout

I am following the [vogella tutoria](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)l about multi-pane development in Android.

Now I would like to check if the a detail fragment is existing (multi-pane layout activated) to remove it and add it again with fresh data. 
I need that to update the detail view when the user selects something in the main fragment.

As suggested in the tutorial I am checking for the Fragment like that:

```
  ReviewMaschineFragment fragment = (ReviewMaschineFragment) getFragmentManager().
                findFragmentById(R.id.detailreviewcontainer);
        if (fragment == null || ! fragment.isInLayout()) {
            Log.i("Detail Fragment", "Start new activity");
        }
        else {
            Log.i("Detail Fragment", "Update...");
        }
```

My Problem is that it always gets false even if the fragment exists. 
Why is it not detecting the fragment as existing if it is present in the multi-pane layout?

I add my fragments like that to the layout:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.maschinelistcontainer, new MaschineFragment());

            if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.dual_pane)){
                ft.add(R.id.detailreviewcontainer, new ReviewMaschineFragment());
            }

            ft.commit();
```

The tablet layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        ></include>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="9"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/maschinelistcontainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
           />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/detailreviewcontainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try fragment.isVisible() for support v4 fragment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While creating fragment add tag value with it 
eg

```
ft.add(R.id.maschinelistcontainer, new MaschineFragment(), "sometag");
```

You can use findFragmentByTag() function to get fragment if it is giving null the fragment is not exist.

```
Fragment fragmentA = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("sometag");
if (fragmentA == null) {
  // not exist
} else {
  //fragment exist
}
```

for example:- http://wiki.workassis.com/android-load-two-fragments-in-one-framelayout/

Answer (score 0):

Pls change

```java
ReviewMaschineFragment fragment = (ReviewMaschineFragment) getFragmentManager().
```

to

```java
ReviewMaschineFragment fragment = (ReviewMaschineFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().
```

Comment: I have changed it to     ReviewMaschineFragment fragment = (ReviewMaschineFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() (it is called inside of a Fragment) but the code still wants to start always to start a new activity even if the detail fragment is present

Comment: If you call in fragment you should use getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: Now I have moved the call into the activity.   ReviewMaschineFragment fragment = (ReviewMaschineFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().
                findFragmentById(R.id.detailreviewcontainer); still wants to start a new activity on tablet. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but this is the solution you suggested first, right?

Comment: because findFragmentbyId maybe return a array of fragment. Pls Try  ft.add(R.id.detailreviewcontainer, new ReviewMaschineFragment(), "detailfragment"); and use findFragmentByTag.